# How many times the constructor is invoked?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, compiler-optimization

I'm a beginner of C++ programing and I have a simple question regarding to the C++ class constructor.
How many times the constructor is invoked for the following code snip?

```
std::string s = std::string("hello world");
```

I guess it's two, right? The first one is string(const char* s), the second one is string(const string& s). Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Next question is that if I compile the code under release mode, will compiler optimize it automatically? e.g. treat it as `std::string s("hello world");` Does different compiler behave differently?

Comment: check the move-constructor in C++11.

Comment: what is the behavior of C++03?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A copy-initialization (with the `=`) where the source type is the same as the destination type behaves very much like direct-initialization. So that initialization is equivalent to:

```
std::string s(std::string("hello world"));
```

With no optimizations, two constructors will be called as you described. In C++11, a move constructor will be preferred for the second step (defined as `string(string&&)`) because  `std::string("hello world")` is an rvalue expression. However, the standard explicitly allows the elision of copies/moves in certain cases, including this one:

> when a temporary class object that has not been bound to a reference (12.2) would be copied/moved to a class object with the same cv-unqualified type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by constructing the temporary object directly into the target of the omitted copy/move

So the compiler may, if it chooses, optimize away the copy. Note that the compiler may do this even if the copy constructor has some strange side effects. That is, it's possible for a perfectly well-defined and valid C++ program to have multiple possible execution paths. Generally, you want to avoid that.

Comment: To be pedantic, it's not "exactly the same", since an implicit constructor needs to be accessible for copy-initialization, and in principle copy-initialization allows the compiler to call two constructors (just in practice no sane compiler ever will).

Comment: @KerrekSB Bad wording on my part. Changed "exactly" to "very much". However, both forms could call two constructors, no?

Comment: Direct-initialization could *not* call two constructors, I'm pretty sure... Actually, very sure, since you can delete the copy constructors and still perform direct-initialization.

Comment: @KerrekSB I mean with the above example `std::string s(std::string("hello world"));`.

Comment: Oh OK. That one would allow one or two times; again, the copy may be elided.

Comment: @JosephMansfield Why would it not my a copy constructor and the a copy assignment call. Giving one copy constructor call total.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is eligible for copy elision, so most sane compilers will always treat this like `std::string s("hello world");` unless explicitly instructed not to do so.